# Ejecutar funcion SQL en asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo definido una función a nivel SQL (GetEstacionParte(int,int)) que me devuelve una tabla, en mi controlador, definí una variable de tipo lista de strings que contenga el resultado de la función, pero la variable siempre trae -1, probé la función a nivel de SQL y funciona, dejo las definiciones de mi método y de mi función ¿en que fallo?, gracias.

Definición de mi método en el controlador:

```
public List<string> GetEstacionParte( int modelo, int estacion) 
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            var modeloint = new SqlParameter("@modelo", modelo);
            var estacionint = new SqlParameter("@estacion", estacion);
            result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEstacionParte(@modelo,@estacion)", modeloint, estacionint);
            return result;
        }
```

La función en SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEstacionParte (@modelo int, @estacion int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN
(
        SELECT dbo.PartEstacion.[cantidad]
      ,P.[nombre] AS Parte
    FROM [YMM_ScrapSystem].[dbo].[PartEstacion] 
    FULL OUTER JOIN Estacion E ON dbo.PartEstacion.IDEstacion = E.IDEstacion FULL OUTER JOIN Parte P on dbo.PartEstacion.IDParte = P.IDParte
    WHERE  dbo.PartEstacion.IDEstacion = @estacion AND P.IDModelo = @modelo
);
GO
```

Y una pantalla de como la ejecuto a nivel SQL y el resultado que trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues, el controlador solo debería recibir y mandar datos, en la capa de aplicación debería estar la lógica necesaria y un repositorio para acceder a los datos.

```
public List<string> GetEstacionParte( int modelo, int estacion) 
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        var modeloint = new SqlParameter("@modelo", modelo);
        var estacionint = new SqlParameter("@estacion", estacion);
        result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEstacionParte(@modelo,@estacion)", modeloint, estacionint).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Ese Resultado contiene la lista. Ahora bien, el problema nuevo es la lista de un solo tipo de elemento, por lo tanto, debes reemplazar `List<string>` por `List<TuClase>`.